# Retorno do SQL SELECT

Tags: php, sql

Preciso fazer um select comparando se login de usuário já é existente ou não. Porém eu não quero que me retorne valores da tabela, apenas um valor simbólico para verificar a existencia(true ou false). O código de comparação é o básico:

```
SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE LOGIN = '$LOGIN'
```

$LOGIN sendo o login que vou comparar. E o select irá me retornar todo conteúdo da tabela desnecessariamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM USUARIOS WHERE LOGIN = '$LOGIN'
```

O *select* retornará **1** se encontrar o usuário e **0** se não encontrar. Semelhante a ***true*** e ***false***.

Comment: desnecessário o 'count' né?

Comment: Não. Muito pelo contrário, sem ele a _query_ teria apenas dois resultados: 1 (se encontrar) ou vazio (se não encontrar). Com o **count** você consegue obter 1 (se encontrar) ou 0 (se não encontrar).

Comment: pelo que eu to vendo, o bom do count é que não voltará um array caso volte mais de um valor né?

Comment: Nesse caso nunca retornará mais que 1 resultado.

Comment: sabe me dizer se tem como da um "Uppercase" na verificação de login = "$login"?? tipo, select count(1) from usuarios where UPPER(LOGIN) = '$LOGIN'...

Comment: Sim, basta usar **upper(login) = upper('$LOGIN')**.

Answer (score 1):

Douglas, tente isso:

```
SELECT 1 FROM USUARIOS WHERE LOGIN = '$LOGIN'
```

SELECT 1 ele 1 caso existir o registro ao invés dos campos da tabela, é muito usado nesse seu caso, que você precisa  verificar a existência de um registro. E caso não exista não retorna nada.

A solução do Electus é boa mas você vai ter que fazer um `if` pra verificar se o retorno foi 0 ou 1 e também ele utiliza a função `COUNT` que vai contar sendo que você sempre vai ter apenas 1 registro que atenda aos requisitos logo desnecessário o uso dessa função, nessa solução proposta por mim se vier registro quer dizer que existe, logo não precisa verificar.

Comment: só que se tiver mais que 1 registro ele volta um array certo?

Comment: Correto! Mas nesse caso especifico dele que é uma tabela de login sempre vai ser apenas 1 retorno.

Comment: O problema é que se não encontrar o usuário, o retorno da _query_ é vazio. Sendo assim ele teria que usar uma função específica pra verificar quantas linhas a _query_ retornou ou se o resultado _"is not empty"_.

Comment: Parti do pressuposto que já tenha essa verificação, pois ele na pergunta não quer retornar colunas que ele não vai usar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer de diversas formas:

```
select id from usuarios where login = '$LOGIN';

select count(*) from usuarios where login = '$LOGIN' limit 1;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/658aa/1)